# Lagom: is number of read side shards set per node or within the whole cluster?

Tags: scala, event-sourcing, lagom

Lagom allows splitting read side processor into shards to scale events processing.

```
object BlogEvent {
  val NumShards = 20
  val Tag       = AggregateEventTag.sharded[BlogEvent](NumShards)
}

sealed trait BlogEvent extends AggregateEvent[BlogEvent] {
  override def aggregateTag: AggregateEventShards[BlogEvent] = BlogEvent.Tag
}
```

Let's say, I have 5 nodes, does it mean that the total number of shards will be 20 x 5 = 100, or will the total number of shards be 20 within the whole cluster?

Answer (score 2):

It's the total number of shards for the whole cluster.

Comment: just to confirm, is it the total number of shards per ALL even tags, or the total number of shard per each event tag?

Comment: @Teimuraz per ALL. One tag is processed on one shard. Otherwise can't organize correct order for processing events tagged the same tag.

Comment: ```object BlogEvent {
  val NumShards = 20
  val Tag       = AggregateEventTag.sharded[BlogEvent](NumShards)
}
``` That means that there will be 20 shards for `BlogEvent`. But I can create another set of shards for other event, let's say `UserEvent` and set `AggregateEventTag.sharded[UserEvent](10)`. So there will be 20 shards for BlogEvent and 10 shards for UserEvent.  Am I right? (Just before I thought that we can only set the number of shards PER ALL EVENTS in the cluster)

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say, I have 5 nodes, does it mean that the total number of shards will be 20 x 5 = 100, or will the total number of shards be 20 within the whole cluster?

`number_of_shards = 20 * numer_of_processors`

Using your example:

```scala
object BlogEvent {
  val NumShards = 20
  val Tag       = AggregateEventTag.sharded[BlogEvent](NumShards)
}
```

in your cluster, no matter how big or small, there will always be 20 instances of each read side processor consuming the stream of `BlogEvent`s. This means that if you created a `BlogRSSReadSideProcessor` and a `BlogAtomReadSideProcessor` and a `BlogTopicProducer`  you would have a total of 60 shards each consuming a particular tag of the stream for its own purposes (RSS, Atom or emitting to a Topic). This means your database will hold 60 connections polling the `Journal` table.